# An app in slack that using a slash command can send messages

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Can anyone help me with how I can create a slash command in Slack that whenever called in a message, will post that message to a certain channel?

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO. Thank your for your question. However, your question does not conform to community standards. Please check the following link on how to ask a good question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think this is a great question @ErikKalkoken I think it would be more helpful to point out what is wrong with the question rather than link to a lengthy doc.